# indexOf is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, indexof

I am checking an index Of string in JAVASCRIPT. and this is coming as false. where as the value does belong to it as below :

```
if(idOfControl.indexOf(idOfButton))  == is giving false for the below values.

idOfControl  = "dlInventory_btnEditComment_0"
idOfButton   = "dlInventory_btnEditComment"
```

But if I run  `idOfControl.replace(idOfButton, "");` It is working and replacing the text.

Any reason for this?

Comment: IndexOf returns the index of string if found else returns -1

Comment: Another option is to use a regex like `control = /dlInventory_btnEditComment/` and then `if (idOfControl.test(control)) {...}`

Comment: it's not `false`, it's `falsy`. That's a big difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`indexOf` can also return 0, in the event of your string being found at the position `0`. `0` evaluates to `false`. Try:

```
if(idOfControl.indexOf(idOfButton) > -1)
```

**More info**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Or `>= 0` which seems more natural to me.

Comment: Or if you want efficiency, `if (~idOfControl.indexOf(idOfButton)) {...}`. However this is harder to read. I don't use it in serious code.

Comment: @paxdiablo `>=0` vs `>-1`, an exciting debate :D

Comment: @wared, I didn't want to start a religious war. I was just stating that the code as given seems equivalent to the English "if this is not an invalid value". Using the `>= 0` transforms it into "if this is a valid value". Granted, the difference can be seen as irrelevant but I'm sometimes anal about double negatives, in both English and programming :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I just wanted to note that it's a matter of point of view. Peace :)

Answer (score 3):

There are these three big options:

## indexOf > -1

The result of `indexOf` can be `0` meaning that the string was found at the beginning of the string. When string is not found, the return value is `-1`, therefore:

```
if (idOfControl.indexOf(idOfButton) > -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Which can be nicer written as @paxdiablo commented:

```
if (idOfControl.indexOf(idOfButton) >= 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

## via regex

You can use a very simple regular expression to test your match.

```
var idOfControl  = "dlInventory_btnEditComment_0"
var control = /dlInventory_btnEditComment/;

if (idOfControl.test(control)) {
    // do something
}
```

This approach can be enhanced to capture the last number of your string (if you need it)

```
var idOfControl  = "dlInventory_btnEditComment_0"
var control = /dlInventory_btnEditComment_(\d+)/;

var match = control.exec(idOfControl);

if (match) {
    alert('the number found is: ' + match[1]);
}
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Z9UC/

## via indexOf in a hacky way

This uses a bitwise operator to return a truthy value when the position is `!=-1` (In two's complement notation, `-1` is internally represented as `111...111`, and its inversion is `000...000` which is `0`, i.e. a falsy value). It is in fact more efficient than the >-1 option, but it is harder to read and to understand. (EDIT: this became so popular that you can say it is a standard)

```
if (~idOfControl.indexOf(idOfButton)) {
    // do something
}
```