# Using indexOf() to compare characters in an Array

Tags: javascript

```
  function mutation(arr) {

  var tester = arr[1].split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < tester.length; i ++) {
    if (!arr[0].indexOf(tester[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
  }

  mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Here I should return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.

I do not see any problems with this code but it passes like only 90% of the tests and I do not know why. And I can not see a pattern there — what exact conditions should I meet to fail the test.

Comment: `arr[0].indexOf(tester[i]) < 0` because `indexOf` returns index of char in a string. Zero based. And -1 if char is not in there.

Comment: `indexOf` function will return an `int`, not a `bool`

Comment: @Mr.Wolf javascript allows `truthy`/`falsey` don't forget. So this would be valid if the user didn't mind missing the first character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indexOf is not working in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065660/indexof-is-not-working-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

[`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns -1 if value was't found, that is why your statement doesn't work.

Change to:

```
if (arr[0].indexOf(tester[i]) < 0) return false;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `(arr[0].indexOf(tester[i]) < 0)` - no `!` ?

Comment: Also: `String.prototype.indexOf() doesn't return false or true`. It can be used as a truthy value. Plus the way the user has it, with `!`, will convert it to a boolean.

Comment: yes, without "!"

Damn, reading MDN article twice really helps. Lack of my own attention really drives me crazy.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Curt `!!-1 === true`

Answer (score 3):

This won't work because you are classing the first position (0 position) as not acceptable.

Your condition will only be true for values which aren't greater than `0`, when `0` should also be valid.

Therefore change it so that it only returns `false` for values which are less than 0.

Change this line:

```
if (!arr[0].indexOf(tester[i])) return false;
```

To:

```
if (arr[0].indexOf(tester[i]) < 0) return false;
```

Comment: Sound like javascript can convert `greater than 0` to `true` :)

Comment: @Mr.Wolf it doesn't convert it to true, but evaluates it as true (truthy) - http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Answer (score 1):

Things were really obvious — Upper/LowerCase() issue. This works now:

```
function mutation(arr) {

 arr[0] = arr[0].toLowerCase();
 arr[1] = arr[1].toLowerCase();
 var tester = arr[1].split('');
 for (var i = 0; i < tester.length; i ++) {
   if (arr[0].indexOf(tester[i]) == -1) return false;
 }
  return true;
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

And of course I have not noticed an obvious 0 position issue:

```
if (arr[0].indexOf(tester[i]) == -1) return false;
```

^ this is correct.

Thanks everyone!